# Prevent Bootstrap Carousel Caption Overlap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, overlay, carousel

So, I am trying to utilize the bootstrap carousel to show content on the page.  The problem is, that when resizing the browser, the captions overlap the content.  I tried changing the captions to be fixed, but that doesn't fix (*rimshot*) the problem.  I thought about putting the captions right below the content and have it flow with it, but I would prefer it to sit on the bottom.  That way it is consistently in the same spot as the user goes from slide to slide.  I tried putting the content down with the caption, but the content goes through the top of the browser.  You will see most of the issue while viewing the 3rd slide.

HTML

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="slideBackground">
                <div class="slideSpacer"></div>
                <div class="slideContent">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non varius nulla. Nulla a sollicitudin purus. Integer pretium ante ac.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Caption for Slide 1 Label</h3>
                <p>Caption for Slide 1 Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slideBackground">
                <div class="slideSpacer"></div>
                <div class="slideContent">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac vulputate orci. Cras tellus quam, tempor eget orci eget, vehicula fermentum neque. In mollis, nisi vel suscipit porta, justo urna tempor erat, et ultricies elit nisl et felis. Morbi quis eleifend purus. Phasellus in est tincidunt, condimentum est vitae, suscipit est. Praesent vel tempor odio, ut consectetur justo. Fusce luctus ornare neque, vitae venenatis risus vulputate ac. Maecenas sit amet ipsum nec libero aliquet euismod nec nec ipsum. Phasellus bibendum faucibus luctus. Nam dapibus posuere purus. Nam quis felis ut orci faucibus imperdiet. Sed sodales lorem vel felis elementum, ut facilisis turpis lacinia. Quisque non laoreet purus, non euismod sapien. Sed pellentesque eleifend vehicula.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Caption for Slide 2 Label</h3>
                <p>Caption for Slide 2 Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slideBackground">
                <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slideSpacer"></div>
                    <div class="slideContent">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et ante lorem. In arcu sapien, porttitor sed elit id, iaculis accumsan turpis. Sed commodo, ligula nec scelerisque semper, ante neque ullamcorper est, et fermentum ipsum ante vel sapien. Phasellus pretium diam odio, vel accumsan lacus fringilla non. Duis interdum lorem vitae magna posuere, ut tincidunt quam posuere. Nunc tristique quis nisi in blandit. Vivamus ultricies sed diam in euismod. Quisque varius ligula et volutpat vehicula. Fusce varius semper urna, sit amet lacinia ipsum ultricies non. Morbi et pellentesque lorem. Donec vehicula fringilla interdum. Integer vitae nisl tellus. Nam eros quam, pulvinar non augue sit amet, eleifend feugiat eros. Vivamus convallis massa ac eros sodales, a congue nisi varius. Nunc turpis nulla, consectetur vitae sagittis ac, lacinia eu erat. Donec congue congue neque vitae tincidunt.
                        <br /><br />
                        Nulla ipsum ante, ullamcorper eu venenatis ac, vehicula vel eros. Sed viverra placerat malesuada. Aenean mattis quam vel risus semper ultricies. Ut euismod, nulla at lobortis pulvinar, lorem nisl tempus arcu, vitae dictum nunc nibh in velit. Vestibulum sed iaculis ligula. In nibh leo, consequat non ultrices vitae, dignissim quis mauris. Suspendisse fringilla cursus interdum. Maecenas mattis elit eu quam semper sodales bibendum vel neque. Nulla rutrum pretium vestibulum. Nam commodo quis turpis vitae sagittis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin non tempus lectus, non dictum magna. Suspendisse vitae varius lectus, eget congue tellus. Etiam luctus condimentum risus, ac gravida enim fringilla vel. Duis aliquam pharetra fringilla.
                        <br /><br />
                        Sed aliquam augue ut dolor molestie scelerisque. Donec leo purus, volutpat sit amet sodales quis, ultricies ut tortor. Vestibulum feugiat ac nibh non feugiat. Suspendisse blandit nibh hendrerit massa consectetur, at suscipit velit tempus. Sed semper, orci porttitor fringilla venenatis, lacus tortor viverra mauris, quis rutrum sem nibh eget libero. Ut eleifend vel odio et posuere. Duis sapien ipsum, convallis ac odio id, fermentum laoreet massa. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque accumsan blandit sodales. Ut sit amet elementum mi. Vivamus accumsan nec nulla sed scelerisque. Maecenas elementum erat id vestibulum sagittis. Aenean semper arcu in tincidunt ultricies. Sed mattis, lacus viverra imperdiet scelerisque, risus erat laoreet magna, ut facilisis augue metus vel enim. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas iaculis eros purus, eget tincidunt turpis malesuada sed.
                        <br /><br />
                        Donec semper felis tempus, euismod purus vel, consequat tellus. Proin dolor magna, dictum sed tristique et, sodales a odio. Donec at mauris enim. Integer accumsan auctor nibh, quis posuere nisl volutpat nec. Morbi suscipit, ligula eget ornare pretium, augue tortor bibendum felis, et gravida nunc ligula quis sapien. Sed in mauris ut felis rutrum euismod sit amet vitae magna. Cras nec pellentesque enim.
                        <br /><br />
                        Pellentesque sed eros eu lacus dignissim commodo. Mauris malesuada fermentum nulla, non congue ligula imperdiet et. Maecenas rutrum dapibus blandit. Quisque vulputate quis lectus eu ornare. Nam magna metus, imperdiet a sodales id, lobortis quis diam. Sed eu sollicitudin felis. Cras vulputate ante id augue pellentesque, id scelerisque turpis dapibus. Mauris sed elit et magna mattis feugiat. Nam turpis est, adipiscing ut mi a, commodo condimentum lacus. Sed vel laoreet lacus, sed ornare sem. Nam a facilisis erat, ut sollicitudin nisi. Duis sit amet velit nec diam feugiat ultricies in non massa. Nullam dapibus, justo non suscipit semper, purus lectus bibendum magna, non laoreet libero dui id est. Donec velit justo, fermentum ac sollicitudin sed, fringilla sed leo. Ut laoreet lorem urna, in laoreet tortor condimentum mattis. Nulla sapien nisl, blandit sagittis tellus quis, consectetur tincidunt lorem.
                        <br /><br />
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut dolor consequat, posuere massa et, auctor ligula. Maecenas feugiat lacinia sem, quis interdum ligula varius quis. Sed purus mauris, porta in cursus ut, gravida quis urna. Duis aliquam, turpis quis accumsan eleifend, nisi quam lobortis leo, id blandit orci est dignissim metus. Donec gravida auctor dui, vitae imperdiet odio vehicula eget. Aliquam non vestibulum nulla. Nullam dignissim vulputate nisl sit amet fringilla. Nunc posuere tellus id luctus interdum. Suspendisse vel sem tortor. Etiam vitae urna at urna placerat pretium ac eu eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis rhoncus, ligula eget laoreet egestas, mauris purus iaculis eros, vitae congue nibh augue eget ante. Donec semper volutpat sagittis.
                        <br /><br />
                        Quisque fringilla, turpis ut pharetra suscipit, mi magna dapibus enim, nec commodo quam quam vitae nulla. Praesent volutpat rhoncus mollis. Etiam dui leo, blandit ut arcu id, sollicitudin gravida eros. Nulla facilisi. Morbi adipiscing risus ut mi tincidunt luctus. Pellentesque gravida lobortis enim eu tempus. Duis sit amet tincidunt eros. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam urna sapien, suscipit vitae ligula non, ultricies ultricies purus. Nam adipiscing sapien feugiat tortor iaculis, vitae volutpat arcu adipiscing.
                        <br /><br />
                        Proin placerat pharetra molestie. Suspendisse vel augue rhoncus leo tristique scelerisque in eu turpis. Vivamus vel consequat diam, sit amet gravida nibh. Vestibulum a varius lacus. Sed sit amet aliquet tellus, vel bibendum mi. Donec in sagittis est, vitae hendrerit lacus. Nunc non tristique felis. Quisque aliquet molestie suscipit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus arcu sapien, vestibulum imperdiet odio eu, imperdiet venenatis nisl. In tincidunt auctor nibh. Mauris nec euismod lacus. Ut eu ligula rhoncus, elementum nunc eu, cursus erat. Donec et faucibus justo.
                        <br /><br />
                        Sed aliquam, magna vel mollis interdum, enim dui facilisis eros, sit amet imperdiet lacus erat id justo. Sed non nisi ut risus lobortis tempor quis vitae lorem. Phasellus id tristique diam. Mauris et turpis semper, lacinia tortor iaculis, hendrerit lacus. Vivamus volutpat nec dolor eget rutrum. Suspendisse urna nulla, faucibus tristique rhoncus nec, posuere at enim. Vivamus accumsan nisl ac consequat euismod. Aliquam molestie vel urna vel gravida. Fusce tristique velit diam. Aliquam in rhoncus velit, ac luctus justo. Nam cursus enim non ipsum hendrerit rhoncus. Ut non risus elementum, adipiscing velit et, blandit velit. Integer eget dolor eleifend, dignissim lectus sed, sodales neque. Suspendisse faucibus sollicitudin pellentesque. Nunc interdum velit nulla, eu interdum turpis vulputate a. Maecenas dignissim non quam ut rhoncus.
                        <br /><br />
                        Mauris aliquet lectus ut nisi volutpat, et congue enim mollis. Vivamus volutpat malesuada tempus. Phasellus tincidunt est risus, a accumsan leo porta a. Suspendisse ac neque in mi interdum elementum. Nulla tristique fringilla elementum. Duis aliquam odio at suscipit suscipit. Nam id tortor non diam vulputate dictum.
                        <br /><br />
                        Donec varius id purus non fringilla. Nunc tempus libero et dignissim viverra. Suspendisse sit amet ultricies lorem, et placerat justo. Morbi tellus velit, vehicula dignissim euismod et, aliquam ac dui. Nunc facilisis quam eget metus consequat, vel ullamcorper odio porta. Cras lacus nisi, varius quis lectus at, sollicitudin ultrices quam. Duis vitae ante nunc. Curabitur suscipit fringilla diam porta dapibus. Quisque sollicitudin tincidunt lectus convallis pharetra. Morbi imperdiet nibh eget tellus tristique eleifend. Phasellus placerat sed ante at pulvinar. Etiam mattis vestibulum lorem nec accumsan.
                        <br /><br />
                        Maecenas eu dignissim diam. Nullam vitae mollis mi, vitae gravida massa. Curabitur tellus libero, gravida a neque a, blandit iaculis ligula. Maecenas aliquam tellus quis ipsum bibendum, et bibendum nisl scelerisque. Donec vulputate lacus sed est commodo scelerisque. Etiam sagittis magna leo. Nam odio ante, semper ac eros in, ultrices rhoncus lorem. Aliquam et ligula posuere leo ultricies tincidunt at vel magna. Phasellus a tellus libero.
                        <br /><br />
                        Phasellus eleifend vestibulum iaculis. Vestibulum sed orci consectetur, facilisis magna ut, molestie tellus. Morbi in dui quis mauris lacinia laoreet. Pellentesque tincidunt sagittis metus, a porttitor est vestibulum nec. Sed viverra porta fringilla. Etiam tempus mi in est condimentum, id tristique mauris dignissim. Quisque ac tellus eu libero suscipit mollis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras ut magna et magna pretium gravida eget nec elit. Pellentesque rhoncus libero neque, a pulvinar risus blandit eu. Donec eu quam nec justo feugiat feugiat eu eu nulla. Pellentesque a erat pretium, egestas nunc sed, egestas sem. Aliquam gravida, neque at fringilla feugiat, leo tellus vestibulum nulla, quis accumsan leo enim nec orci.
                        <br /><br />
                        Vestibulum nec diam mauris. Suspendisse sapien elit, pretium sed consequat nec, ultricies ac ligula. In pellentesque, elit nec sodales consequat, mauris magna vestibulum urna, et porta lectus nisi sed dolor. Sed vel porttitor magna, at semper orci. Nulla facilisi. Integer non tortor id neque posuere vestibulum at quis risus. Maecenas congue diam ut est dapibus scelerisque. Quisque non iaculis orci, dapibus rutrum justo.
                        <br /><br />
                        In porttitor scelerisque erat quis pulvinar. Phasellus vehicula est sit amet turpis facilisis vulputate. Phasellus elementum urna at varius vestibulum. Nullam commodo varius leo et pulvinar. Aliquam tempus vehicula accumsan. Mauris in rutrum felis. Donec non risus sem.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideCaption">
                    <span>Caption for Slide 3 Label</span>
                    <p>Caption for Slide 3 Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 51px;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

    .carousel-inner > .item {
        height: 100%;
    }

.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 150px;
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

    .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        padding: 3px 10px;
    }

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}





.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.dropdownItemContainer {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdownItemBadge {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.dropdownItemText {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideBackground {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
}

.slideCaption {
    height: 20%;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    background-color: purple;
}

.slideContainer {
    height: 80%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.slideContent {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    max-height: 80%;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    overflow: auto;
}

.slideIndicatorsSpacer {
    height: 20px;
}

.slideSpacer {
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

I'm running out of ideas to try.

*UPDATE*: I was able to get the captions part to work by wrapping the content with a div height set to 80% and moving the captions into the item and setting the height to 20%.  I updated the HTML and CSS above.  The ISSUE now is, the indicators will now overlap the captions.  This is a bit trickier as one carousel only has one set of indicators and I can't move them into each item like I could the captions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a height for carousel-caption?

```
.carousel-caption {
    max-height: 20%;
}
```

Because the slide content has a max-height of 80%, if the height of the caption exceeds 20% it will end up overlapping

EDIT FOR UPDATE:
The carousel indicators will overlap beuuase they have a set distance from the bottom of the screen. As the caption height isn't set, but is a percentage of the overall height, the indicator distance will run the risk of being greater than the caption height.
Try setting the caption height to something fixed?

```
.slideCaption {
    height: 100px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the indicators will still overlap the captions.  The issue is that the indicators are position: absolute.

Comment: What about with carousel-indicators {bottom: 0px}? It would ensure the indicators are as low as possible, thereby giving the caption more space

Comment: It works for the percentages I have 80% (Content) and 20% (Caption).  But, for other perecentages, it does not.  I am continuing to experiment.